# Python Kivy widget animation

Tags: python, animation, widget, kivy, scatter

I've posted similar topic recently, but this time I'll try to be more clear and specific. My problem is that widgets in Kivy aren't animating as they are expected to. Here's some example code, why are scatters better to animate than widgets:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class ExampleWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (100,100)
        self.pos = (100,100)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)
            self.texture = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

    def on_pos(self, obj, value):
        try: self.texture.pos = value
        except: pass

class ExampleScatterTexture(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScatterTexture, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0,1,0)
            texture = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

class ExampleScatter(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScatter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_rotation = False
        self.do_scale = False
        self.do_translation = False
        self.size = (100,100)
        self.pos = (100,300)
        texture = ExampleScatterTexture(size=self.size)
        self.add_widget(texture)

class ExampleScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = Window.size

        example_widget = ExampleWidget()
        self.add_widget(example_widget)

        example_scatter = ExampleScatter()
        self.add_widget(example_scatter)

        #SCATTER IS GREEN, WIDGET IS RED
        example_widget_animation = Animation(pos=(300,100), duration=2., t='in_bounce') + Animation(pos=(100,100), duration=2., t='in_bounce')
        example_scatter_animation = Animation(pos=(300,300), duration=2., t='in_bounce') + Animation(pos=(100,300), duration=2., t='in_bounce')
        example_widget_animation.repeat = True
        example_scatter_animation.repeat = True
        example_widget_animation.start(example_widget)
        example_scatter_animation.start(example_scatter)

class BadAnimationExample(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ExampleScreen()
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BadAnimationExample().run()
```

As you can see, the widget animation is executed very fast and then there comes a pause, while scatter animation is very much like we expect it to be. My problem is that when I have my finger on the scatters all my on_touch_move() functions aren't working. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem. I used my on_touch_move() method in the child widget class and the solution is to use it in the parent widget. Then there is no problem with scatter selection.